# jquery validation loop producing false positives

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, textbox

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
// hides the story and error text when the page loads
$('.errorText').hide();
$("#story").hide();

// global variables for the blanks and the textarea forms
var input = $("form").children();
var storyBlank = $('#story').children();

// Main Event on Click
$('button.submit').on( "click", function (event)
{
    // if the form is not validated, highlights errors and prevents the submit from going through
    if(!validate())
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    // if the form is validated, fills the blanks in the story and displays it
    else
    {
        fillInTheBlanks();
    }
});

// Checks to see if there are any empty fields and highlights them if they are empty
function validate()
{
    console.log('validate() initiated')
    var success = false;
    errcnt = 0;
    cnt = 0;

    while (cnt < 9)
    {
        if (input.eq(cnt).val().length == 0)
        {
            errcnt++;
            input.eq(cnt).removeClass("hide");
            console.log('errorcount', errcnt, 'at input', cnt);
        }
        else if (input.eq(cnt).val().length !== 0 && !(input.eq(cnt)).hasClass("hide"))
        {
            input.eq(cnt).addClass("hide");
        }
        cnt++;
    }

    if (errcnt == 0)
    {
        success = true;
    }
    return success;
}

// Fills in the blanks of the story
function fillInTheBlanks()
{
    console.log('fillInTheBlanks() executed');
    var blankCount = 0;
    while (blankCount < 9)
    {
        storyBlank.eq(blankCount).empty().append(input.eq(blankCount).val());
        blankCount++;
    }
    $("#story").show();
}
});
```

I am trying to make a mad libs style page with 9 textboxes for input. I am running into two problems.

First, when I click submit with all textboxes empty, only the the first four show an error (this is done in css, I have two classes on all the textboxes "error hide", I remove the class hide in my loop to show the error).

The second problem I'm having is if I click submit with text in all the textboxes, my validate functions errorcount goes up to 4 errors at every other textbox. I've even tried '$('input').eq(0).val().length == 0' for every textbox in the index and it's returning false every time. I don't understand how it's getting into that if then statement if it doesn't satisfy the argument.

Comment: I know this isn't what you were trying, but this option just seems a lot easier and simpler. [HTML5 Required](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i don't understand your problem, but if is validation on inputs empty... using

http://parsleyjs.org/